# Flutter pass TextField input to another widget via Navigation.push

Tags: flutter

I need to pass whatever user type in TextField and then use it in another stateful widget. How can I pass data in myController of TextField. I am using this to search API based on user input and need to pass this data at time of navigating to another screen

```
TextField(
controller: myController,
decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
hintText: ' Search by Product Name',),
onSubmitted: (value) { Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ProductBySearch()));},),
```

```
class ProductBySearch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductBySearchState createState() => _ProductBySearchState();
}

class _ProductBySearchState extends State<ProductBySearch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
        future: getProductByBanner1(http.Client(), mycontroller),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ProductByBanner1Grid(
              product: snapshot.data,
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    Container(
                      height: 15,
                      width: double.infinity,
                    ),
                    Text('Factory2Homes'),
                  ],
                ));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass the data to the constructor of the `Widget` built in the `MaterialPageRoute` builder. This data being the `myController.text` itself.

```
class ProductBySearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductBySearch({Key key, @required this.productName}) : super(key: key);

  final String productName;

  // (...)
}
```

And then

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductBySearch(
  productName: myController.text,
))
```

---

I invite you to read [Send data to a new screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) Flutter Cookbook tutorial. It should explain you the concept fairly well.

Comment: Saved my day! :) . I was confused on how to pass data if there is no Class like Todo